# Capybara warns of "checking for expected text of nil"

Tags: rspec, capybara

When I'm running tests, I happen to see this in my terminal window for a specific feature spec that I'm running:

```
Checking for expected text of nil is confusing and/or pointless since it will always match.
Please specify a string or regexp instead.
```

I don't believe that my code has any improper use of `nil` so I'm wondering what it means. I'm also not using `nil` in any rspec expectations or capybara methods. Is there a way for me to help troubleshoot this message further?

Comment: Please show your spec - Capybara would only output that message if `nil` was being passed in to a text matcher as the expected value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by a variable that is nil while checking e.g. `expect(page).to have_text user.middle_name` where in this case user.middle_name is nil because the user has no middle name.

The warn message is issued in your "gems-directory"**/gems/capybara-x.x.x/lib/capybara/queries/text_query.rb**.

To find out where the nil check occurs add `raise "here I check for nil"` before the `warn`.

You will get a runtime error with the line where it occurs in your spec.

```
RuntimeError
  here I check for nil
# ... stack trace omitted
# ./spec/requests/user_show_spec.rb:45:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>
```

Comment: The trace is added on https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/commit/922d6614762518c82bc53a3bc83b816a4beb186d so should be easier on the next version.

Comment: I can confirm that the trace does appear in 3.36.0.

Answer (score 1):

I made a mistake in using an instance variable, something like `page.should have_text @foo`, but I had not used or initalized `@foo` anywhere. Bad mistake on my part.