# Capybara warning Unexpected confirm modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

It looks like Capybara is issuing a deprecation warning when I run my complete test suite. The warning is

```
Unexpected confirm modal - accepting.You should be using `accept_confirm` or `dismiss_confirm`
```

but no trace is given, so am having difficulty tracking down which part of my code is causing the problem.

How do I fix this?  It would be useful, as demonstrated in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63376447/1299362), to show where in the capybara code I can insert an exception to find where this is happening in my code.

Comment: That message isn't coming from Capybara (not in the current version code), so it's likely coming from whichever driver you're using.  In which case, easiest way to debug that would likely be to configure whichever driver to not auto accept unexpected modals.

Comment: Thanks Thomas.  I am using is your apparition driver, I have looked at the README and cannot see how to 'not auto accept unexpected modals'